# Spreadsheet UI - User prompted to open or save userAppPanel from docs.google.com

Tags: google-apps-script

My UI works for me (I'm the spreadsheet owner and script creator).  However, when I share the spreadsheet with other users, the UI does not display fully and they are prompted to open or save the `userAppPanel` from docs.google.com.

I've complete cut down my script to the following, still not luck:

```
function showDialog() {
    // Create the UI application
    var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication();

    // Provide the Popup with a title
    uiApp.setTitle('Parameter Collection Dialog');

    // Create an user instruction label
    var lblInstructions = uiApp.createLabel()
      .setText('Select a type of Person and Country');

    // Add the panel to the application
    uiApp.add(lblInstructions);

    // Show the application in the spreadsheet
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    spreadSheet.show(uiApp);
}
```

The UI works when the the script is run from the script editor for every user that tries - however, when I hook it up to an "on open spreadsheet" trigger, the script only works for me - and no-one else.

I'm so close to nailing my requirement and this is a very frustrating last hurdle.

Many thanks

**Update:  Please see my comment for a solution i.e. use onOpen function rather than a manual onOpen trigger.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for confirming Srik. However, I have worked out a solution:

I was hooking up the showDialog function to the On Open trigger, manually through the script editor. but, if you change the showDialog() function name to onOpen(), then you don't have to hook up the function to the event manually as onOpen is a built in event, and it now works for all users (providing they are shared users, and logged in).

I will open an issue too, as I believe it should work both ways.

Hope my solution helps others too :)

Answer (score 0):

I've attempted to recreate the problem and was able to do so easily. This appears to be a bug. I suggest you open an issue in the [Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) and update this thread with the bug number.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the workaround with renaming the function onOpen is not always applicable, for instance when you need the function to run under the identity of someone (yourself for example). If you rename it onOpen(), it will run under no identity. I cannot do that because I need to authenticate into a database.

This seems to confirm that the problem is linked to the identity of the person triggering the script.

have you posted an issue ? Could you please share the link to it ?

Comment: More details about this after a few tests. It seems it is due both to user triggering the script to execute, as well as characteristics of the trigger :
- if the function is called from a custom menu in a spreadsheet, everything works fine for everyone
- as said above, if function is called onOpen(), everything works fine for everyone
- if function is triggered by a function on which an installable onEdit or onOpen function has been set, then everything works fine for the person who set it, and bad for others.
The last behavior is observed whether that person is owner or not.